# Can a low density material be used to build a marine propeller?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Does the density of propeller material matter in the propulsion of the ship or does only the strength matter? For example, can we use carbon fiber material to build the propeller? What might be the effect on the movement of the ship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density or rotating mass of a ship's propeller is not an important design limiter. The strength of the material from which it is made is, and so is its corrosion resistance.

Carbon-fiber propellers can be made for use in water, but the weight savings that high-tech composites furnish do not matter in that arena. They matter a lot in aeronautical applications, where weight minimization is very important.